# Can you pass arguments to many constructor methods in C#?

Tags: c#

Sorry if this is a newbie question but can you pass arguments to many constructor methods in C# ? True or False ?

I am taking an exam on C# with ASP.NET but there is no answer in the book or on many forums I've looked in so far.

Comment: What do you mean with "many constructors"? You can call another constructor from a constructor and pass the argument.

Comment: arguments or parameters?

Comment: I guess you are talking about overloaded constructor.

Comment: To be honest I really don't know. That is exactly how the question was on the exam.

Comment: As a true or false question. No code to back it up.

Comment: The answer ended up being true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question right, you're looking for something like `Constructor-Chaining`

```
public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
            : this(string.Empty)
        {

        }

        public Class1(string val1)
            : this(val1, string.Empty)
        {

        }

        public Class1(string val1, string val2)
            :this(val1, val2, string.Empty)
        {

        }

        public Class1(string val1, string val2, string val3)
        {
            // Do something with the val's
        }
    }
```

Comment: `+1` please mention that this is called `Constructor Chaining`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by passing arguments to many constructor methods.

I don't know if this helps.

You can have multiple constructors for a given class with different parameters(Overloading). This is what the polymorphism is all about.